# How to install NPM on Debian?

Tags: debian, installation, debian-stretch, npm

Can somebody please help with installing NPM in Debian?

First I tried `apt-get install npm` but got this message:

> Unable to locate package npm.

So I followed the [installation steps for Debian from nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions). The first command:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
```

gave this message:

> sudo command not found.

But if I install packages do not have to write `sudo` so I deleted it and got this message:

> -E command not found

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have `sudo` installed, then your command string should be this instead:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Comment: That didn't work out of the box because debian still wanted to install the old version of nodejs not the one from the repo.

I fixed that by forcing debian to install latest version of nodejs

1.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew's answer was really helpful but didn't work out of the box because debian still wanted to install the old version of nodejs not the one from the repo.

I fixed that by forcing debian to install latest version of nodejs

I ran `apt-cache policy nodejs` to know the version of latest nodejs package
Then once I figured that out I ran `apt install "nodejs=<latest_version>"` at the time of writing it was `apt install "nodejs=9.11.2-1nodesource1"`